# Click on thumbs show different text in same area

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make text1,2,3 showing in same div. And when I click on different image to change text and close previous.

http://jsfiddle.net/XfCvm/

This is script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slickbox').hide();
  $('a#slickbox-toggle').click(function() {
      $('#slickbox').slideToggle(400);
      return false; 
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#slickbox1').hide();
    $('a#slickbox-toggle1').click(function() {
        $('#slickbox1').slideToggle(400);
        return false; 
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slickbox2').hide();
    $('a#slickbox-toggle2').click(function() {
        $('#slickbox2').slideToggle(400);
        return false; 
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slickbox3').hide();
    $('a#slickbox-toggle3').click(function() {
        $('#slickbox3').slideToggle(400);
        return false; 
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="ponuda">
    <a id="slickbox-toggle" href="#"><img src="http://hotelpalicresort.rs/wp-content/themes/palic/images/specijalna-ponuda.png" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="130"></a>

    <a id="slickbox-toggle1" href="#"><img src="http://hotelpalicresort.rs/wp-content/themes/palic/images/specijalna-ponuda.png" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="130"></a>

    <a id="slickbox-toggle2" href="#"><img src="http://hotelpalicresort.rs/wp-content/themes/palic/images/specijalna-ponuda.png" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="130"></a>

    <a id="slickbox-toggle3" href="#"><img src="http://hotelpalicresort.rs/wp-content/themes/palic/images/specijalna-ponuda.png" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="130"></a>
</div>

<div  id="slickbox">
    TEXT   
</div>
<div  id="slickbox1">
    TEXT1   
</div>
<div id="slickbox2">
    TEXT2   
</div>
<div id="slickbox3">
    TEXT3   
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your fiddle is missing jquery, you can add it around the top left. You should also explain the specific issue you are having with your code

Comment: What's your requirement can you please explain more like what you want to do

Comment: Please correct your jsFiddle to reference jQuery. You can select it in the menu on the left of the page.

Comment: it works http://jsfiddle.net/XfCvm/1/..

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a full suggestion in order of readability and simplicity. I modified your markup to achieve that. Please let me know if that is not possible.

HTML:

```
<div id="ponuda">
    <a id="slickbox-toggle" class="slickbox-toggle-class" href="#slickbox"><img src="http://hotelpalicresort.rs/wp-content/themes/palic/images/specijalna-ponuda.png" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="130"></a>

    <a id="slickbox-toggle1" class="slickbox-toggle-class" href="#slickbox1"><img src="http://hotelpalicresort.rs/wp-content/themes/palic/images/specijalna-ponuda.png" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="130"></a>

    <a id="slickbox-toggle2" class="slickbox-toggle-class" href="#slickbox2"><img src="http://hotelpalicresort.rs/wp-content/themes/palic/images/specijalna-ponuda.png" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="130"></a>

    <a id="slickbox-toggle3" class="slickbox-toggle-class" href="#slickbox3"><img src="http://hotelpalicresort.rs/wp-content/themes/palic/images/specijalna-ponuda.png" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="130"></a>
</div>

<div  id="slickbox" class="slickbox-class">
    TEXT   
</div>
<div  id="slickbox1" class="slickbox-class">
    TEXT1   
</div>
<div id="slickbox2" class="slickbox-class">
    TEXT2   
</div>
<div id="slickbox3" class="slickbox-class">
    TEXT3   
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slickbox-class').hide();
  $('#ponuda a.slickbox-toggle-class').click(function() {
      $('.slickbox-class').hide();
      $($(this).attr("href")).slideToggle(400);
      return false; 
  });
});
```

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/W6SLF/

Comment: check out my answer to see that you don't necessarily need to assign classes to the ids that have numbers in order in them!

Comment: @AminJafari I know that, but could cause a lot of problems if you're not careful. For example adding a new element with this id `#slickbox-wrapper` besides of course the efficiency between use class and parse&search inside ids.

Comment: of course it is more elegant to add classes, it is good coding! but in some simple cases it is a very good jQuery practice to try to achieve it only using ids, as I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't use javascript, because template is limited and only accsepts jquery. Regards!

Comment: @AminJafari Don't missunderstood me it's completly valid use attr selectors and as you said is more simply in a close case and of course the only way if modifing the markup isn't an option

Comment: @ralezmaj I think you mean that you can't modify the html markup isn't it? Because not only jQuery IS javascript but also there isn't a single line of standard javascript in this answer!

Answer (score 0):

here you go, didn't change anything in your code, just the jQuery => http://jsfiddle.net/XfCvm/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
      $('div[id^=slickbox]').slideUp(0);

  $('a[id^=slickbox-toggle]').click(function() {
      var index=$(this).index();
      $('div[id^=slickbox]').not(':eq('+index+')').slideUp(400);
      $('div[id^=slickbox]').eq(index).slideToggle(400);
      return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmm.. good if looking for a short js script but bad if considering about readability. (imo)

Comment: I agree, as I mentioned, it is just a good practice! @MaunoV.

Comment: @ralezmaj would you care to accept the answer if it is in fact what you needed?

Comment: just click on the check mark beside my answer, that's how you can accept the answer as the correct one! @ralezmaj

Answer (score 0):

Well, we all have different ways of doing things. I tried to remove duplicate code and make it more readable:

See code comments below and usage of `data-slick-content` attribute which contains your div content :)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="ponuda">

    <a href="#" class="toggle-slick" data-slick-content="TEXT"><img src="http://hotelpalicresort.rs/wp-content/themes/palic/images/specijalna-ponuda.png" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="130" /></a>

    <a href="#" class="toggle-slick" data-slick-content="TEXT1"><img src="http://hotelpalicresort.rs/wp-content/themes/palic/images/specijalna-ponuda.png" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="130" /></a>

    <a href="#" class="toggle-slick" data-slick-content="TEXT2"><img src="http://hotelpalicresort.rs/wp-content/themes/palic/images/specijalna-ponuda.png" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="130" /></a>

    <a href="#" class="toggle-slick" data-slick-content="TEXT3"><img src="http://hotelpalicresort.rs/wp-content/themes/palic/images/specijalna-ponuda.png" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="130" /></a>
</div>

<!-- See that we declare this as hidden by default, choose as you like -->
<div id="slickbox" class="hidden">
    <!-- By default, we have TEXT-->
    TEXT 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#ponuda{
    display:inline;
}
#slickbox {
    background-color:#e1dbdb;
}
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  /**
   * Method for showing slickbox content
   *
   */
  var toggleSlick = function(content) {

      // Push new text to an element slickbox
      $("#slickbox").html(content);

      // Show the element
      $('#slickbox').slideToggle(400);

  };

  // Bind clicks for all toggle-slick links
  $('.toggle-slick').click(function() {

      // Capture content from data-slick-content (e.g. TEXT1)
      var content = $(this).data("slick-content");

      // Hide previous if visible
      if($("#slickbox").is(":visible")) {
          $('#slickbox').slideToggle(400, function() {
             // Animation complete
             toggleSlick(content);   
          });

          return false;

      } 

      toggleSlick(content);

  });

});
```

Here is **[js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XfCvm/6/)**

Cheers.